# Vue/Javascript - the best way to write this ternary

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ternary-operator

I am looking for the most efficient way to write this ternary.

```
id === this.mygroup ? this.mygroup = ''  : this.mygroup = id;
```

This is in a vuejs method but I suppose it does not matter.

Should I copy to a local var so it does not read it multiple times?

```
let activeGroup = this.mygroup

 id === activeGroup ? activeGroup = ''  : activeGroup = id;
```

Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.mygroup = id === this.mygroup ? '' : id;`

You assign `this.mygroup` to either `''` or `id`, which is what you want